# NoneType error when trying to access .text attribute of an existent <a> element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the first wikitable on the page [List of military engagements during the Russian invasion of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_engagements_during_the_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine) to get the names of all 57 battles. I have attached an image of the table's HTML for reference: [HTML of the wikitable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teErr.png).

To grab all the `<a>` elements in the first column and get just the text (the battle names), I did the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_engagements_during_the_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')

battlenames = []
for row in rows:
    # Find the first <td> element within the row
    td_element = row.find('td')
    if td_element:
        # Find the first <a> element within the <td> element
        battlename = td_element.find('a')
        cleanname = battlename.text
        battlenames.append(cleanname)

for name in battlenames:
    print(name)
```

I ran this in both Spyder and Jupyter Notebook and got the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 18
     15     if td_element:
     16         # Find the first <a> element within the <td> element
     17         battlename = td_element.find('a')
---> 18         cleanname = battlename.text
     19         battlenames.append(cleanname)
     21 for name in battlenames:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This surprised me because the first `<td>` element of every row (`<tr>`) contains an `<a>` element with the battle name. I.e., there are no empty boxes in the table's first column that would cause a NoneType error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

Based on comment from @Ouroboros1 to be more precise, the issue is exactly, that there are elements of `td` that do not contain a `a`.

> table contains one "sub" tr for "Battles of Voznesensk", where the first td fills "9 March 2022" in the "Start date" column. Now, this td just happens to have no link `a`

So you have also to check if there is an `a` before calling `.text`:

```
if td_element:
    # Find the first <a> element within the <td> element
    battlename = td_element.find('a')
    # check hier if also a is available
    if battlename:
        cleanname = battlename.text
        battlenames.append(cleanname)
```

---

You could also try to change your selection strategy, may use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select only `tr` with `td` that contains `a`:

```
soup.table.select('tr:has(td:first-of-type a)')
```

or even directly all `a` in first `td` of `tr`:

```
soup.table.select('tr td:first-of-type a')
```

##### Example css selectors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_engagements_during_the_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

#Option A

for row in soup.table.select('tr:has(td:first-of-type a)'):
        print(row.td.a.text)

#Option B
for a in soup.table.select('tr td:first-of-type a'):
    print(a.text)
```

Comment: Very nice. However, this does not properly address the reason why this happens to work (and what was wrong with the OP's own attempt). The issue is that the table contains one "sub" `tr` for "Battles of Voznesensk", where the first `td` fills "9 March 2022" in the "Start date" column. Now, this `td` just happens to have no link (`a`). I suppose it would be more robust to check `if len(row) == 12`, as the sub `tr` has a length of 4. Would be great if such a filter could be passed to `select`, but I don't know how one would make that work :).

Comment: @ouroboros1 Thank you, good point and indeed I should have gone into more detail. I have taken up your points, a check for 12 columns is also an approach, but here too a check would have to be made for the presence of the a, as only then is the actual error avoided if there is no a in the first of the 12 columns.